# Move to the latest file in the jumplist

Tags: vim

With vim, I like to use `C-o` and `C-i` to move through the jumplist and I want to use the same to move to the previous and the next file with `<leader>o` and `<leader>i`.

I know I can use the buffer but the list is not always the same.

I tried to use [EnhancedJump](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2695) but I have some bugs and it seems to be obsolete.

Do you have solution?

Comment: I'm the author of EnhancedJumps; what makes you think it's obsolete? It hasn't been updated for a long time because it works _perfectly_ for me :-)

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I will add an issue so. I thanks it was not maintained anymore. Thanks.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I cannot submit an issue on Github. I have the error "Unknown function: ingo#msg#VimExceptionMsg". What is the best way to submit an issue?

Comment: Not all of my plugins are yet on GitHub; you've probably found the _vimscripts_ mirror of www.vim.org. You could write me an email next time (yep, I'm that old(-fashioned)).

Comment: Your problem is a missing dependency to my _ingo-library_. You also need to install my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433); it's also on [GitHub](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-ingo-library). It's listed as a DEPENDENCY in the plugin's INSTALLATION section.

Comment: ok thanks. I will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be possible with functions like that:

```
function! JumpBack()
  let l:cfile=expand('%')
  let l:nfile=l:cfile
  while l:cfile == l:nfile
    execute 'normal ' . 1 . "\<c-o>"
    let l:nfile=expand('%')
  endwhile
endfunction
```

*Note this could be written cleaner, it is mostly pasted togheter.

However it seems like a sledgehammer method for me, maybe there is a better one.

---

### Update

It was not surprising to hear, that this would lead to an endless loop if the jumplist only contains one file. Here is a better solution:

```
function! JumpBack()
  let l:cfile=expand('%')
  let l:jl = split(execute('jumps'), '\n')
  let l:jumpcounter = 0
  for l:jumpline in reverse(l:jl)
    let l:jumpcounter = l:jumpcounter + 1
    let l:nfile = split(l:jumpline, '\s')[-1]
    if l:cfile != l:nfile 
      execute 'normal '. l:jumpcounter . "\<c-o>"
      return
    endif
  endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: @Dougui ist this a question or a comment? you just have to replace `<c-o>` with `<c-i>`.

Comment: There is an infinite loop when we are at the beginning of the jumplist. It do `c-o` but still at the same place so it stay in the `while`. We can probably find something to check in the output of `:jumplist`.